# How to track size change of div

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I need to track size change of div control. Is there are any event like `onresize` that works for div? How could I do this? It should works in IE and Firefox.

Comment: Is the div changing size due to the window being resized? E.g. fluid layout. Or are you manually changing the div's size? Also, are you using any JS libraries?

Comment: div's size changed by SharePoint script. So, I can't add any function call to this script. Also, I use jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect DIV's dimension changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492683/how-to-detect-divs-dimension-changed)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it is to check size of div with short period of time.
Anyway you will not get it smooth.