# Removing event listeners as Class.prototype functions

Tags: javascript, oop, dom-events

I'm trying to have a Class.prototype based classes in my project, where I don't have inline functions. Considering this example, it's impossible to remove the eventListener on `myVideo` video object, that I have in my class.

*This is a theoretical example, not an actual production code I have.*

```
var myClass = function () {
    this.initialize();
}

MyClass.prototype.myVideo = null;

MyClass.prototype.initialize = function () {
    this.myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    this.myVideo.addEventListener("ended", this.onMyVideoEnded, false);
    this.myVideo.play();
}

MyClass.prototype.onMyVideoEnded = function (event) {
    // cannot remove event listener here
    // this.myVideo.removeEventListener("ended", this.onMyVideoEnded, false);
}
```

Is there a way to leave the handler as a Class.prototype function and add and remove listeners. I need to instantiate and create a lot of objects of this sort, and am afraid of memory leaks, and object persistancy (all of previously created objects receive the "ended" event) when leaving anonymous functions not removed as event handlers.

Or should I just consider a different approach (inline functions, inside the initialize function, as event handlers). These really impact readability and consistency, so I want to avoid them on all costs.

Comment: A handler is a listener, right?  I don't really understand your question ...

Comment: A handler is a function, that get's executed when the event fires. A listener is a language construct, that calls the handler function, when it [listener] detects, that the event has fired (I'm not sure, how event listeners work under the hood).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) your function `onMyVideoEnded` with context where you attached it:

For example:

```
this.myVideoEndedHandler = this.onMyVideoEnded.bind(this);
this.myVideo.addEventListener("ended", this.myVideoEndedHandler, false);
```

To remove listener also use stored handler:

```
this.myVideo.removeEventListener("ended", this.myVideoEndedHandler, false);
```

This is because when event triggers your function `onMyVideoEnded` gets wrong `this` argument.

Comment: `foo.bind(bar) != foo.bind(bar)`, you wont be able to correctly remove the event listener, unless you store a reference to the originally bound listener.

Comment: This is elegant and pretty straight forward, though not trivial coming from ActionScript background. I thank you, oh so very much! I feel the joy of life once again. :}

Answer (score 1):

i use this:

```js
this.element.handler = handler.bind(this);
this.element.removeEventListener('event', this.element.handler, false);
this.element.addEventListener('event', this.element.handler, false);
```

or use a WeakMap object:

```js
var handlers = new WeakMap();
```

```js
var self = this;
handlers.set(this.element, { handler: handler.bind(self) });
```

```js
var handler = handlers.get(this.element).handler;
this.element.removeEventListener('event', handler, false);
this.element.addEventListener('event', handler, false);
```