# Is it possible to call a class method with addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Just something I've been wondering. In the second parameter in the `.addEventListener` method, can you call a "(custom) class method" instead of a function?

i.e Would something like the following work?

```
var object = new ClassName();
document.getElementById('x').addEventListener('click', object.method, false);
```

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "work". Have you tried it? How/where is `method` defined? What does it need to do? It might "work", or it might not.

Comment: The code was just off the top of my head. I haven't tested it. I've never touched OOP in JavaScript before so this was just something I was wondering.

Comment: Well then the answer is "maybe". If `.method` is indeed a function, it'll be passed as the handler, but without knowing what it does, it may or may not "work".

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as a "custom class method". `object.method` is still a normal function it will look like any other function to `addEventListener`. There is no implicit relationship between a function and the object to which it is assigned as property value. Imagine you have `function foo() {...}; obj.method = foo; obj2.method2 = foo; var bar = foo;`. So, after your logic, what is `foo` now? What does it "belong" to?

Comment: By "custom class method", I meant anything other than built-in methods . Hence the quotes. Sorry, if that was confusing.

Comment: Opps, just realized I didn't use quotes.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, what you've written wouldn't work, in that `method` would be invoked without `object` as its context. Inside `method`, `this` would be set to the DOM element which initiated the event.

If you want to invoke the method and retain the context, close over the `object` variable with a function:

```
var object = new ClassName();
document.getElementById('x').addEventListener('click', function () {
  object.method()
}, false);
```

Comment: +1 You probably know this, but for the OP's benefit I'll comment anyway. *this* is not "context", it's a parameter of an [execution context](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10). For functions it's set by how the function is called (or by using *bind*). It can be set to any object (or any value at all in strict mode). .

Comment: Then how do you remove that same event listener? That's my challenge right now.

Comment: This solved it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720927/javascript-removing-event-listeners-as-class-prototype-functions

Answer (score 19):

I just tried a more direct approach, it appears to work and I'd say it's pretty clean. I just add `bind(this)` to the argument to `addEventListener()`. Don't make it complicated when it's not...

```
class HTMLExample extends HTMLElement{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.count = 0;
    this.addEventListener('click', this.onClick.bind(this), false);        
  }
  
  onClick(event){
    let prevCount = this.count;
    this.count++;    
    let msg = `Increased Count from ${prevCount} to ${this.count}`;
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += `${msg}<br/>`;     
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Most of answers use [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), but you can achieve it by simply writing.

```
class EventHandler {
  constructor(element) {
    element.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handler); 
  }
  // just declare the method as a property with arrow function.
  hander = () => {
    console.log(this);
  }
}
```

I wrote the full working code sample at [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/9re/pen/abayeEv).

Comment: This worked well, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Yes is possible by doing a binding.

Below, I'm creating a Web Component. A feature that is supported in most browsers.

To create this Web Component, I'm creating a class that extends the `HTMLElement` class. As far as JavaScript goes, this is just another regular class.

Now, I want my Web Component to behave like a button.
I want a counter to be increased each time my tag gets click on.

*Note: The three dots is an indication that "more code" goes there.*

So, I create a variable that will hold the count inside the constructor:

```js
constructor(){
  ...
  this.count = 0;
  ...
```

Then, I add a listener that detects when my Web Component is click on and call the method `onClick`:

```js
constructor(){
  ...
  this.count = 0;
  ...
  this.addEventListener('click', this.onClick, false);        
}

onClick(event){
 let prevCount = this.count;
 this.count++;    
 let msg = `Increased Count from ${prevCount} to ${this.count}`;
 document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += `${msg}<br/>`;     
 }
```

The onClick is designed to increase the counter and print the previous and current value in the counter; however, **there is a problem here!!!**

The problem is in this line `this.count++;`. The keyword `this` isn't referring to the instance of the class `HTMLExample`. The reason is that functions added with `addEventListener` will reference the bound element as `this`, not the function or object.

Therefore, you must do a binding of that function, used by the `addEventListener` to the instance of your class by adding this line of code:

```js
this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
```

Now, when you use the `this` keyword inside the method `onClick`, the `this` will be referring to the instance of the class `HTMLExample`.

Please check the code below and run it. I think it will become clear that way:

```js
class HTMLExample extends HTMLElement{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.count = 0;
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    this.addEventListener('click', this.onClick, false);        
  }
  
  onClick(event){
    let prevCount = this.count;
    this.count++;    
    let msg = `Increased Count from ${prevCount} to ${this.count}`;
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += `${msg}<br/>`;     
  }
}
customElements.define('example-component', HTMLExample);
```

```css
example-component{
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<example-component>Button</example-component>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers here were helpful but still left me wondering if there was a tidy syntax to do basically the same thing. I didn't want to pass a reference to a class instance to itself, that's just weird.

Here's a tidy pattern that keeps everything inside the class with no need to use the instance reference, but a closure instead.

```
myclass= function(){};
myclass.prototype.addSystemEvents = function(){
  var scope = this;
  window.addEventListener( 'resize', function(){scope.onWindowResize();}, false);
}
myclass.prototype.onWindowResize = function(){
   //do whatever
}
```

Comment: In your class:
window.addEventListener("keydown",(e)=>this.keyDown(e));

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You need to invoke the method and retain the context, close over the object variable with a function:

```
var object = new ClassName();
document.getElementById('x').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  object.method(e)
}, false);
```

If you invoke without inside function, the 'this' would be set to the DOM element which initiated the event.

Comment: can you please explain to me, how context is being changed when we close over the object variable with a function?

Earlier it was sending the context as the DOM element that initiated the event but closing over with a function changes the context but HOW?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible, just take care with the context. E.g.

```
ClassName.prototype.click_handler = function(el) {
    // Here 'this' doesn't refer to the instance
    // of ClassName but to the element clicked
}
var object = new ClassName();

document.getElementById('x').addEventListener('click', object.click_handler, false);
```

Comment: @rvighne: That was a pretty radical change you made to this answer.

Comment: @cookiemonster Not really. The original answer had a good heart, but it throws a JavaScript error (you can't set prototype of an instance). Obviously we can't have that. I believe this does what Sergio intended.

Comment: Right. It radically changed the meaning of the answer to something entirely different.

Comment: @rvighne thanks for the edit suggestion. I don't know what was I thinking about!

Answer (score 0):

For anybody using typescript or Babel/Transpilation, this was the cleanest way I could think of, I'm sure there's room for improvement!

```js
class Person {
    name = "bobby"
    sayGoodbyBound = this.sayGoodby.bind(this);
    sayGoodby() {
        console.log('Goodbye, my name is', this.name);
    }
}

const person = new Person();
let element = document.createElement("button")
element.addEventListener("click", person.sayGoodbyBound);

element.click()

// remove same one
element.removeEventListener("click", person.sayGoodbyBound);
```

Answer (score 0):

For TypeScript users, here's a neat example: crafting an `Autobind` [Decorator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html).

Saves you from manually binding everywhere. Just bind it like this:

```
function Autobind(_target: any, _methodName: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    const adjDescriptor: PropertyDescriptor = {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: false,
        get() {
            const boundFn = originalMethod.bind(this);
            return boundFn;
        }
    };
    return adjDescriptor;
}

class Printer {
    message = 'Omakase';

    @Autobind
    showMessage() {
        console.log(this.message);
    }
}

const p = new Printer();    
const button = document.querySelector('button')!;
button.addEventListener('click', p.showMessage);
```

Here is a live demonstration available on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-21298918?file=index.ts).