# I can't call a class function inside another class function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class

I want to call the function "displayTime" in "startTimer" but for some reason I get "Uncaught TypeError: this.displayTime is not a function" in the console.

```
let endTimer = "0";
let isRunning = false;

//! CLASS
class Timer {
  constructor(endTimer, isRunning) {
    this.endTimer = endTimer;
    this.isRunning = isRunning;
  }

  startTimer() {
    if (this.endTimer === "0") {
      this.endTimer = new Date().getTime() + 1500000;
    }
    displayTime();
    if (this.isRunning === true) {
      this.pauseTimer();
      this.isRunning
    }
    this.isRunning = true;
  }

  displayTime() {
    let now = new Date().getTime();
    let remainingTime = this.endTimer - now;
    let minutes = Math.floor(remainingTime / 1000 / 60);
    let seconds = Math.floor((remainingTime / 1000) % 60);
    if (seconds < 10) {
      seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    timer.innerHTML = `<h1>${minutes}:${seconds}</h1>`;
    start.textContent = "STOP"
    this.update = setInterval(this.displayTime, 100);
  }
}

let newTimer = new Timer(endTimer, isRunning);

//! EVENT LISTENERS

start.addEventListener("click", newTimer.startTimer);
```

I think that I'm missing something obvious, but I don't understand what...

Comment: Have you tried referencing it instead as `this.displayTime()`?

Comment: There's a duplicate for this but the TL;DR is that when you pass the `startTimer` function reference to `addEventListener`, it is detached from the class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to call a class method with addEventListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21298918/283366)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maintaining the reference to "this" in Javascript when using callbacks and closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874723/maintaining-the-reference-to-this-in-javascript-when-using-callbacks-and-closu)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, it works!

Answer (score 1):

Calling displayTime(); without the prepended keyword 'this' is the main issue (line 16 below) as mentioned by [GenericUser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4282081/genericuser) and [Heretic Monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/heretic-monkey) in the comments above.

You probably already know this but you'll want to define a pauseTimer() method/function as well.

```
let endTimer = "0";
let isRunning = false;

//! CLASS
class Timer {
constructor(endTimer, isRunning) {
    this.endTimer = endTimer;
    this.isRunning = isRunning;
  }
}

Timer.prototype.startTimer = function() {
    if (this.endTimer === "0") {
        this.endTimer = new Date().getTime() + 1500000;
    }
    this.displayTime(); // this is the important line
    if (this.isRunning === true) {
        this.pauseTimer();
        this.isRunning
    }
    this.isRunning = true;
}

Timer.prototype.displayTime = function() {
    let now = new Date().getTime();
    let remainingTime = this.endTimer - now;
    let minutes = Math.floor(remainingTime / 1000 / 60);
    let seconds = Math.floor((remainingTime / 1000) % 60);
    if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    //timer.innerHTML = `<h1>${minutes}:${seconds}</h1>`;
    //start.textContent = "STOP"
    this.update = setInterval(this.displayTime, 100);
}

Timer.prototype.pauseTimer = function() {
    this.isRunning = false;
}

let newTimer = new Timer("0", true);
newTimer.startTimer();

//! EVENT LISTENERS

//start.addEventListener("click", newTimer.startTimer);
```

Comment: I actually messed up in the code I uploaded and it was indeed "this.displayTimer" that I was calling, so the problem wasn't this one. It was a matter of event listener from what I can see by other comments: `start.addEventListener("click", () => {
  newTimer.startTimer();
})`
This works fine and calls startTimer correctly, same as with the method .bind(). The problem now is that it seems like I can't click the "start" button again, it just doesn't register the click for some reason. Maybe it is because the object isn't the same anymore? I don't really know

Comment: It's ok, I solved the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```js
start.addEventListener("click", newTimer.startTimer.bind(newTimer));
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Now the problem is that if I click the same button again, the same function isn't going to be called. Is it a side effect of .bind()? How can i call the function again?

Comment: It's ok I solved the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Timer {
    startTimer() {
        // You forgot this keyword
        this.displayTime();
    }
    displayTime() {
        console.log('do something');
    }

}

let newTimer = new Timer();

// addEventListener changes the context of this.
// Using an arrow function will keep 'this' keyword in tact inside startTimer method 
start.addEventListener('click', () => newTimer.startTimer)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).