# Pass a puppeteer based client object to onClick button inside a puppeteer page

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, puppeteer, browser-automation

I have a non-common use case I'd like to implement. I found an open source project that uses puppeteer to automate action within whatsapp web. It provides a client object with an API to listen to events or do some actions such as

```
client.on('message_create', (msg) => {
    client.sendMessage(number, text);
    
});
```

I'm not so proficient with JS, but what I understand is that it launches a real instance of whatsapp web and then interacts with it.

What I want to do is - once whatsapp web is loaded, add a div with buttons that would interact with my wrapper app functions and do automated stuff.

I did manage to add external button to the UI and set it's onClick, I done it via the the page.evaluate function, something like that:

```
await client.puppeteerPage.evaluate(async () => {
    let btn = document.querySelector('#updateIcButton');
    btn.addEventListener("click", async ()=>{ 
        // Do some action with the client, however - client is undefined here
    });
   
 });
```

So far so good, but now comes the problem - what I want to do is to interact with the client functions inside the click listener, which I currently found impossible to do since inside the 'evaluate' function which is the only way I found to inject buttons, the client from the upper scope is undefined... I couldn't find a way to pass the client object as it creates a cyclic dependency or something if I pass as parameter.. Also tried other stuff such as calling exposeFunction or addScriptTag but nothing seem to be working.

I'm not sure it's possible anyhow, as although I'm not so proficients with JS and web dev, I understand that the web page doesn't "know" or can't interact with the puppeteer application wrapping it.

I'd appreciate if someone can please suggest a way to solve or another possible way to add UI that can interact with my puppeteer application and do automated stuff within the page instance.

Appreciate your help!

More of my source code:

```
client.on('ready', async () => {

  await client.pupPage.exposeFunction("sendMessage", client.sendMessage);
  client.pupPage.evaluate((divHtml) => {
    
   //here I have logic to load a div container with a single button
    //Once the div is added, I'm querying the button ID and trying to set it's onClick to interact with the client from above
   let btn = document.querySelector('#updateIcButton');
   btn.addEventListener("click", async ()=>{ 
       // Do some action with the client
       sendMessage("phonenumber","sometext"); // trying to call the func I exposed
   });
  }, divHtml);
});
```

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks for the quick response. the library is: 
https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js

I tried to expose functions in few ways but for example here's a reference which I'm sure is not a good practice but I have no much idea what I'm doing:

await client.pupPage.exposeFunction("sendMessage", client.sendMessage);

As you can see I'm exposing function from the client itself, to a page found as a property within the same client.. I can also share my entire code if it's helpful but there's no much there.. Just started using this library

Comment: Thanks again @ggorlen , I edited my post and added a minimal reproducible example at the bottom as requested, please let me know if it's helpful or whether more info is needed

Comment: Can you try `exposeFunction("sendMessage", (number, message) => client.sendMessage(number, message));`? You might want to `await sendMessage()` in the browser as well.

Comment: Comment of the year! Thank you so much for such a quick resolution on something I considered impossible. Very appreciated. @ggorlen

Comment: No problem. Related in the sense that both are about binding class methods to event listeners: [Is it possible to call a class method with addEventListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298918/is-it-possible-to-call-a-class-method-with-addeventlistener)