# The class instance method passed to a function causes this to be undefined Javascript

Tags: javascript

The following piece of code screams due to `this` being undefined.

```js
function myFunc(f) {
  console.log(f());
}

class Test {
  potato = "potato";

  test() {
    return this.potato;
  }
}

const t = new Test();
myFunc(t.test);
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Use `myFunc(t.test.bind(t))`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298918/is-it-possible-to-call-a-class-method-with-addeventlistener