# Javascript - resizable DIV

Tags: javascript, html

- I try to create movable and resizable div using pure javascript
- the resizable div have 4 handler in corner to control it e.g :

  - northeast : a div located in     y=0, x=0;
  - northwest : a div located in     y=0,x = max parent width;
  - southwest : a div located in     y=max parent height, x = max parent width
  - southeast : a div located in     y=max parent height,x = 0

(note: the handler location is relative to parent, the parent is the resizable div)

I'm getting difficulties with the logic to resizable..

Here's what I try

- when user click the div, I insert it 4 div (use as handler) (this happen at event onmousedown)
- now the handler will do the job

  - **northeast**:

    *I don't know the logic*
  - **north west**

    *I don't know the logic*

    my suggest : when user move this handler towards

    - y axis : the parent y position will equal to y position of this handler(but the height is weird)
    - x axis : the parent width will equal to x position of this handler
  - **south west**:

    when user move this handler towards

    - y axis : the parent height will equal to y position of this handler
    - x axis : the parent width will equal to x position of this handler
  - **south east:**

    *I don't know the logic*

    my suggest : when user move this handler,

    - y axis : the parent height will equal to y positon of handler.
    - x axis : the parent x position will equal to x position of handler. (but the width is weird, this is that bug me out)

(Note : the handler position = absolute)

I already goggle but I still can't solve it.

What to do?

Apologize can't post a code because in actual I have 8 handler and my code is untidy.

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960193/how-to-make-html-element-resizable-using-pure-javascript

Comment: @Mr.G thanks.. the links only use 1 handler, in my case it use only handler south west. my logic seems right for handler south west. i just dont understand with the logic on the other handler