# How can I let the client actively resize a column in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

How do I let the user resize a column in bootstrap?

I made a responsive layout in Bootstrap like this.

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-3 app-left-hand-side'>
      <!-- tool bar goes here eventually -->
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-9'>
      <!-- the main content goes here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I let the client actively resize the columns by dragging along the border in the middle?

Comment: Consider using jQuery UI with the resizeable feature, you can make the other element resize too in the resize or stop events to ensure everything flows smoothly. http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#event-resize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't with bootstrap but with javascript you can do as described here:

[How to make HTML element resizable using pure javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960193/how-to-make-html-element-resizable-using-pure-javascript)

Or use jquery:

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#divId" ).resizable();
  });
```

http://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Comment: Just a heads up, that's jQuery UI, not jQuery. (jQuery UI is pretty heavy to add if it's only for this feature).