# How to resize div with CSS by the border

Tags: javascript, css

How would I let a user resize a div? I would like them to be able to grab the side of it and pull it, I **DO NOT** want CSS Resize property. The Resize property makes the part you drag to make it bigger in the corner. So how would I let a user make a div bigger by grabbing the side?

Comment: you may want to add javascript to your question tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don’t want to use the `resize` property, there’s no other option to do this with CSS. However, you can achieve this with JavaScript.

There are libraries that support this, e.g. jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Of course, it’s also possible to do this in plain JavaScript. However, it’s tricky due to differences in the browser’s implementations. **[How to make HTML element resizable using pure javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960193/how-to-make-html-element-resizable-using-pure-javascript)** might be a good starting point.