# How to resize a div with cross brower support for IE10+

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser, resize

I'm trying to resize a `div` element.

I managed to do it by using `resize:` css property like so:

http://codepen.io/bengedi/pen/GJMpPd

But it doesn't work with IE.

how can I make it work on IE10+ with css and/or js only (not jQuery).

Comment: What do you actually try to achieve? There's no resizeable elements in your codepen example when opened with FF. What does not work in IE?

Answer (score 0):

CSS `resize` is not supported by IE. This is for reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp

Can you please explain what actually you're looking for?

There are few way to resize element. Example:

**Using CSS**

```
.normal {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.normal.resized {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

**Using Javascript**

Assume you have `<div class="normal"></div>`

```
var div = document.querySelectorAll('.normal');
div.style.width = 400;
div.style.height = 200;
```

**Using CSS Transform**

```
.normal {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.normal.scaled {
  transform: scale(1.2); // Scale 120%
}
```

If you try to ask "How to create cross browser resizable div?", you can check answered question: [How to make HTML element resizable using pure javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960193/how-to-make-html-element-resizable-using-pure-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
I'm trying to be able to resize some div when pressing on the bottom right corner of the current div, much like my codepen example: http://codepen.io/bengedi/pen/GJMpPd
and doing it in javascript so it will work on IE10+.

Thanks