# How can I resize a panel WITHOUT using resizable method in either jQuery or pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a program that resizes a panel to the top, bottom, and it also goes over the second panel without shrinking it. My code runs just fine, but I don't know how to do it WITHOUT using the resizable method in either jQuery or JavaScript.

Here's my code that works just fine.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#orangeBox" ).resizable({
        handles:'n'
    });
 });
```

Here is a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/hyq86sva/1/

Comment: why don't you wanna use the resizable() method?

Comment: maybe this would help you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960193/how-to-make-html-element-resizable-using-pure-javascript

Comment: @user2517028 It's a challenge question and I'm not allow to use the resizable method

Comment: @user2517028 that example only uses 1 box and I'm using two panels. Also the resizable panel needs to go over the other one

Comment: @d_omicic I got it working a while ago, but I guess nobody could've done it haha. It's all good though

Comment: @d_ominic just wanted to see if there was someone brave to do it that's all.

Comment: @programadorxpert Nobody responded cuz this isn't a place to ask for work to be done for you.

Comment: @d_ominic This task was not even a hard, just wanted to get a hint not do it all for me.