# Change the size of an element by mouse(or touch in mobile) using javascript (or css ,that's better if possible), not considering the jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I wanna change the size of an element by mouse(or touch in mobile) using javascript ( pure javascript or css ,that's better if possible). And it must be very smooth both in mobile and desktop(I wanna do an online editor,smooth is importnat).

And I know one way to do that using jquery:

```
$( "#resizable" ).resizable();
  });
```

I wonder how to do that effect in pure js or css only?
or do you have a more efficient way to do that in an online editor using just html and javascript?

Comment: Not using jquery,I am considering it's to big for mobile and i donot want the online-editor too big, so I thought it will be better if i code it using pure javascript or css,  and also practice my learning of javascript. I hate frameworks like jquery in which you need to upload all stuff ,which most you don't use at all.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate question to me. [See here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960193/how-to-make-html-element-resizable-using-pure-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use the code from the below link and use it as your requirements

Comment: just using mouse to drag it so that the width of the div can be changed dynamically

Comment: You Can use the code from the below link and modified it as per your wish but in js it will be bit lengthy . Link is http://codepen.io/zz85/pen/gbOoVP

Comment: IT seems very good example for me. I will look more deep into it. Thanks

Comment: you can remove that div and can work without it and delete all the reference in the code it is just to set the boundary on first look it seems

Comment: Could you please edit this answer so it contains the complete solution instead of requiring future visitors to read the comment thread to understand how to solve the issue?