# How to create handles on each side of a div for resizing? - (NO jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

Using pure javascript HTML5 and CSS3 (NOT jQuery)

I want to do something like this image, I have HTML elements inside the div, like for example a text area or text box, when user clicks on the container div I want the handles and border to show up.  THe user should resize the container only using the handles.

How can I accomplish this?  I know how to do the events and resize, but not sure how to specifically create the handles and resize only on those points.

Are the handles a CSS trick?  or do I have to create a graphic for the container (like a background image on the resizable div container?)

Comment: *I want to do* ... show what you have tried ...

Comment: @DaniP uh, I don't know where to start? everything I found was in jQuery, alternatively I found the way to add standard bottom right hand corner resize handle using css but that's not what  I want.

Comment: I think that you can find the answer of this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960193/how-to-make-html-element-resizable-using-pure-javascript)

Comment: What you can do is add a container that provides those points as separate elements, and then bind the events you already know to each point.

Comment: @DaniP Ok, What do you suggest to make the handles from?  Are they drawn using pure css, an graphic or maybe a tiny div with a border?  I guess they could be anything as long as I can attach the event to it.

Comment: It can be CSS .. https://jsfiddle.net/0sgun0dr/1/

Comment: How about a Canvas element?  I would assume thet you could make it partially transparent and put it over the div.  It might also be relatively browser agnostic.  You have to realize that jQuery goes through a lot of work working with the quirks for each browser.  When you want to do something like this, I would worry about major changes required for each browser release.

Comment: @BradleyRoss assume I'm working for nothing lower than IE11, and the latest FF and Chrome.  Does that concern still apply?

Comment: When it comes to adoption of HTML5 capabilities, Firefox and Chrome have different schedules.  There are also things in Javascript for which there is not necessarily a defined result.  I found a number of cases where Chrome, Firefox, and Safari reacted to code differently.  Internet Explorer is an anti pattern collection all by itself.  I generally tried to stick to the items that would work on multiple browsers without browser dependent code.  I like to work on the KISS principle. (Keep it simple, stupid.)  When you go for the "cute", expect high maintenance.

Answer (score 8):

First you can use CSS like this:

```
div {
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

(http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp);

At this post was a good Javascript example:
([How to make HTML element resizable using pure Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960193/how-to-make-html-element-resizable-using-pure-javascript))

JS Example:

- https://github.com/anhr/resizer