# Resize div vertical or horizontal

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to resize div vertical or horizontal not using css property just resize from  height or width using pure javascript code?

Comment: Show some code of what you have tried, or how you are trying to implement the change.

Comment: <div id="clickable" style="background-color: aqua;width:100px;height: 100px;">

</div>

<script>
    var clickable = document.getElementById("clickable");

    clickable.onmousemove = function(event){
        var x = e.clientX;
        var y = e.clientY;
        var coor = "Coordinates: (" + x + "," + y + ")";
        document.getElementById("clickable").innerHTML = coor;
        
        document.onmouseout = function (event) {
//            document.getElementById("clickable").innerHTML = "";
        }
    }
</script>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div id="top-panel"> This is the top side's content! </div>
<div id="bottom-panel">
  <div id="drag"></div> 
  bottom content!</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var isResizing = false,
lastDownX = 0;

$(function () {
var container = $('#container'),
    top = $('#top-panel'),
    bottom = $('#bottom-panel'),
    handle = $('#drag');


document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
isResizing = true;
    lastDownX = e.clientY;
});
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){

    // we don't want to do anything if we aren't resizing.
    if (!isResizing) 
        return;
    console.log("e.clientY ", e.clientY, container.offset().top)
    var offsetRight = container.height() - (e.clientY - container.offset().top);

    top.css('bottom', offsetRight);
    bottom.css('height', offsetRight);
}); document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e){
    // stop resizing
    isResizing = false;
});
```

});
[resize div veritcally](http://jsfiddle.net/T4St6/2156/)

Answer (score 2):

I found the best results to be the following:

```
 var div1 = document.getElementById("DivOne");
 var dRect = div1.getBoundingClientRect();

 var scrollBarWidth = 6;
 var w = window.innerWidth - 2*dRect.left - scrollBarWidth;
 var h = window.innerHeight - 2*dRect.top - scrollBarWidth;
 div1.style.width = w.toString()  + "px";
 div1.style.height = h.toString()  + "px";
```

Working Example: [Single DIV sized to the document window](https://bl.ocks.org/sfanjoy/raw/521b200c5f49d669a15d2709d237b0fa/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the `style`
e.g.

```
getElementById('div_register').style.width='500px';
getElementById('div_register').style.height='500px';
```

Comment: no you dont understnad me you must you use there cursor from resize vertical or horizontal

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function handleContainerHeight(e) {
        const container = document.querySelector("#elmentToResize");
        container.style.height = `${e.clientY}px`;
    }

    const handleDragMouseDown = (e) => {
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleContainerHeight);
        document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleDragMouseUp, { once: true });
    };

    const handleDragMouseUp = (e) => {
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleContainerHeight);
    };
```

```html
     <div className="resize-container">
                    <div className="resize-wrapper" onMouseDown={handleDragMouseDown}>
                        <img src="image.png" alt="Drag Icon" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow.
You could improve your answer by adding some text description to the source code