# JS resizable div

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to create `div` element which behaves similar to clicking and dragging on Windows desktop.

So far I my code does the following:

- We *create* (just changing CSS styling of display:none to display:block) a `div` when the page detects a mousedown
- If the user moves the mouse while still mousing down, they modify the size of the div.
- When the user releases the mouse button, we hide the div (display:none)

My problem is the **resize** part. Right now, the div can be expanded in a South East direction only.

Refer to this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3d7zo1w/8/) an example.

Play around with the Fiddle example to see what I mean (you cannot expand vertically beyond origin, for example).

The reason, I assume, is becuase `newX` and `newY` are negative values. How can I solve this?

Comment: You might want to start here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960193/how-to-make-html-element-resizable-using-pure-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make HTML element resizable using pure javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960193/how-to-make-html-element-resizable-using-pure-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't consider the case where mouse move coordinates are less than the drawing start coordinates, I have modified the JS code a bit,

```
var clientBox = document.getElementById("userBox");
var startX, startY, currentX, curentY;

function initRect(event) {
    startX = event.clientX;
    startY = event.clientY;
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", drawRect);
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", dstryRect);

}

function drawRect(event) {
    var width = event.clientX-startX;
    var height = event.clientY-startY;
    var x = startX;
    var y = startY;
    if (width < 0) {
        x = startX + width;
        width=-width;
    }
    if (height < 0) {
        y = startY + height;
        height = -height;
    }
    clientBox.style.display = "block";   // Hideen until click detected
    clientBox.style.top  = y + "px";
    clientBox.style.left = x + "px";
    clientBox.style.width = width + "px";
    clientBox.style.height = height + "px";
}

function dstryRect() {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", drawRect);
    window.removeEventListener("mouseup", dstryRect);
    clientBox.style.display = "none";
    clientBox.style.height = "0px";
    clientBox.style.width = "0px";
}
```

just update these chnages in JS file and you are done.
Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3d7zo1w/24/)
Thanks.

Comment: This solution works great, but could you explain how it works please. Also note that you never used your declared variables named `currentX` and `currentY` ;)

Comment: @FlameStinger My mistake, the variable currentX and currentY are declared for current mouse position, but I used directly the event.clientX and event.clientY, so you can remove these two declarations.

Comment: And about the code, the startX and startY stores the starting X and Y when mouseDown occurs, and during mouseMove, it compare the current x and y with the starting x and y and decides is it just moving in NW, NE, SE or SW direction, and then if height and width is calculated and check its negative, if yes then change the top and left the rectangle to the currentx and current y and negate the height and width.