How to resize and drag an image using vanilla JavaScript
I have a simple Mr Potato Head game with a big Mr Potato Head and a side bar filled with parts. I would like to make the parts, which are images, both draggable and resizable.
The following is the website code, with the dragAndResizeElement function responsible to add event listeners for both the dragging and resizing functionality. I call this function on every image when it is dynamically appended to the parent container of all the Mr. Potato Head parts. The dragging functionality works perfectly, however the resizing functionality does not work at all. I would love help in figuring out the best way to make these images dynamically resizable by the user. I have attached a picture of how the website looks on the screen since the code does not run properly without the folder of images in the directory.
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            /*background-image: url(images/background3.jpg);*/
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 25% 75%;
            column-gap: 5em;
        }

        #mrPotatoHead {
            width: 75%;
        }

        #bodyPartDiv {
            border: 2px solid black;
        }

        .part {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <audio xautoplay loop src="media/Children's Music - Kids Game.mp3"></audio>

    <div id="bodyPartDiv"></div>
    <img id="mrPotatoHead" src="images/mr-potato-head/body.png">

    <script src="game.js"></script>
</body>

async function loadParts() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('parts.json');
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`${response.status} - ${response.statusText}`);
            }
            const json = await response.json();
            return json.images;
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }

    const parts = await loadParts();
    parts.forEach(part => {
        const img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = part;
        img.className = 'part';
        partDiv.append(img);
        dragAndResizeElement(img);
    });

    function dragAndResizeElement(element) {
        let dragging;
        let resizing;
        let translate = { x: 0, y: 0 };
        let client = { x: 0, y: 0 };
        let originalWidth, originalHeight;

        element.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (e.offsetX > (element.offsetWidth - 20) && e.offsetY > (element.offsetHeight - 20)) {
                element.style.cursor = 'nw-resize';
                resizing = true;
                originalWidth = element.offsetWidth;
                originalHeight = element.offsetHeight;
            }
            else {
                element.style.cursor = 'grabbing';
                dragging = true;
            }
            client.x = e.clientX;
            client.y = e.clientY;
        });


        document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (dragging) {
                translate.x = translate.x - (client.x - e.clientX);
                translate.y = translate.y - (client.y - e.clientY);
                element.style.transform = `translate(${translate.x}px, ${translate.y}px)`;
            }
            else if (resizing) {
                const newWidth = originalWidth + (e.clientX - client.x);
                const newHeight = originalHeight + (e.clientY - client.y);
                element.style.width = `${newWidth}px`;
                element.style.height = `${newHeight}px`;
            }
            client.x = e.clientX;
            client.y = e.clientY;

        });

        document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
            element.style.cursor = 'grab';
            dragging = false;
            resizing = false;
        });
    }



Creating a game from scratch is way harder than using a game engine, so if your game is still in early stages searching for a game engine maybe an option to consider. But if you want to implement the resizing yourself I recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/q/8960193/146513 . And if that doesn't help I recommend to improve this question by making clearer what you tried and which exact part is not working from the resize and which parts of the code works as expected. Try to divide the problem into smaller pieces so the question is easier to understand and more likely to generate interest.
