# Attach function to dynamically created DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Goal:**

Append a DOM element with functionality. (One global listener is not desire here.)

**Problem:**

I don't know how to reference the new element in this context. The problem area is the `.on` event listener and the references to `$(this)` contained inside. Also, the ability for the function `get_value()` to call itself again from within.

**Relevant Code:**

```
var dom_element = (function() {
    // [...]
    var create = function create( data ) {
        // [...]
        return $('<div />', { 'class': 'element', id: data.i_id })
            // [...]
            .on('load', function get_value() {
                // [...]
                $(this).find('.value').text(s_value);
                // [...]
                setTimeout('get_value()', 5000);
            }());
    },
    // [...]
    return {
        create: create
    };
}());
```

Comment: Don't pass strings to `setTimeout`, it `eval`s them.  Pass functions: `setTimeout(get_value, 5000);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `load` event won't work on a `<div>` element.

If you want to perform some action when the content of the `div` is updated, you should do so in the code that updates the content.

```
var dom_element = (function() {
    // [...]
    var create = function create( data ) {
        // [...]
        var div =  $('<div />', { 'class': 'element', id: data.i_id })
            // [...]
        (function get_value(div) {
            // [...]
            $(div).find('.value').text(s_value);
            // [...]
            setTimeout(function() {
                get_value(div);
            }, 5000);
        })(div);

        return div;
    },
    // [...]
    return {
        create: create
    };
}());
```

I updated the code to do what I assume you're looking for.

Comment: He can use `mutation events` as well.  (Yes I know they're deprecated...)

Comment: @gdoron: What's a "mutation event"?

Comment: @gdoron: True. I think I was misunderstanding the intent of the code at first. Seems like it's just an update on an interval.

Comment: @Rocket. [mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents). [Example why it's needed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9628472/601179).

Answer (score 1):

As another had said, on.('load'...) doesn't apply here.  You're creating these elements dynamically (presumably after the DOM is all ready) so you should be able to start the timeouts right away.  Here's my take:

```js
var make_new = function(data){
    var $div = $('<div>', {'class': 'element', 'id':'element_'+data});
    var func = function(){
        // closure has formed around data, $div, and func
        // so references to them here reference the local versions
        // (the versions outside this immediate function block. i.e,
        // inside this call of make_new)
        data++;
        $div.text($div.attr('id') + ":" + data);
        setTimeout(func, 1000);
    };
    func();  //start process rolling
    return $div;
};
```

Basically, you should take advantage of js closures to capture the references that you need.  func() is called before returning the div element, but there's nothing stopping you from returning both the element and func, and calling func() later.

Check out the jsfiddle of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/gRfyH/

Answer (score 0):

The scope of a event handler is always the element, so using `this` you're doing everything right to reference the created `<div>` from `get_value`.

Yet, when you call `get_value` from the timeout, it will be executed in the global context. So you need to [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function to the element before passing it in `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(get_value.bind(this), 5000);
```

Or you do it manually:

```
var el = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    get_value.call(el);
}, 5000);
```