# Detecting a change in height for a div using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to fire a function every time a div has a change in height. How can I do this?

Comment: Here is a good example for your question : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628450/jquery-how-to-determine-if-a-div-changes-its-height-or-any-css-attribute][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628450/jquery-how-to-determine-if-a-div-changes-its-height-or-any-css-attribute

Answer (score 1):

A good way is to use DOM mutations to verify every change in a specific part of the markup.

For example, you can use the [jQuery mutate official plugin](http://jQuery%20mutate%20official) to detect if the height of something changed and launch a callback.

You can try this:

```
$('div.monitor').mutate('height',function (element,info){
      console.log('a div with  has changed it\'s height, the function below should do something about this...');
      $(this).css('background','red');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var divHeight = $("#share-something-textarea").css("height");
    setInterval(function(){
        if(divHeight !== $("#share-something-textarea").css("height")){
            //something here
        }
    },200);
});
```

I think you can set a setInterval that verify every x ms the div height.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, anyway I think this solution is by far the best.
There is a Jquery library called Jquery Mutate that was created right for things like these.

(Current Supported events: width, height, top, right, left, bottom, hide, show, scrollHeight, scrollWidth, scrollTop, scrollLeft).

If you would like to fire a function every time a div has a change in height, you can do something like this:

First import the library:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>  
<script> google.load("jquery",'1.7'); google.load("jqueryui", "1"); </script>  
<script src="mutate.events.js"></script>  
<script src="mutate.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can use this code:

```
$('#div').mutate('height',function (element,info){  
    console.log('a div changed it\'s height, the function below should do something about this...');  
    $(this).css('background','red');  <-- example of action triggered after the event height changed  
});
```

Here you find the **official website** of Jquery Mutate: http://www.jqui.net/jquery-projects/jquery-mutate-official/

And a **demo** that shows how flexible it is:  http://www.jqui.net/demo/mutate/