# resize event handler is not calling when element's size change

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

i have a resizable svg element in my html body tag. However, when I resize it, no function is called.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('resize', 'svg', function() {
        console.log('svg is resizing');
    });
});
```

When the svg element's size changes, this function should be called. However, I don't see any "svg is resizing" output in my console. Please explain why this code isn't being called.

Comment: I think `resize` handler is for `window` element. Have you tried it with `$(window).on('resize'......);` or `$(window).resize()` ?

Comment: You're using the `resize` event incorrectly. You're supposed to bind it to the `window` or bind it to an element and trigger it manually e.g. `$('svg').trigger('resize');`. If you tell us what you want to do when the SVG is resizing then there might be another solution.

Comment: What makes your SVG size change?

Answer (score 1):

In normal usage, the `resize` event is only sent to the `window` object when the window is resized -- that's the only time it's triggered by the browser. You could trigger that event programatically on any element using the .trigger() function, but there's no `resize` event normally triggered when the size of an element changes, and if you knew when to trigger that event, you could just run the code in your event handler anyway.

That said, you aren't out of luck -- it'll just require a bit more code than that. Here is a link to a previous question which may be of use to you in accomplishing your goal: [Determining if a div changes height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628450/jquery-how-to-determine-if-a-div-changes-its-height-or-any-css-attribute).

Comment: Is there event triggered when size of an element changes ??i have to call a function when size of svg element changes. Thanks

Comment: There's no event normally triggered, but I added a link to a question which may help in figuring out how to track that change. EDIT: Actually, there MAY be an event called "SVGResize"... I'm not familiar enough with working with SVGs to know whether that's relevant or not. Here's the documentation though: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#ResizeEvent

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your SVG element:

```
<svg ....  onresize="console.log('resized');">
   <g>...</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Worked in Chrome but not in Firefox for me