# Change paragraph content when height of a div reaches a certain percentage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a loader for a website. The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="loadingContainer">
    <div class="greyContainer">
        <img class="eggGrey" src="img/egg-grey.png">
        <p id="bluePercent">50%</p>
    </div>

    <div class="blueContainer">
        <img class="eggBlue" src="img/egg-blue.png">
        <p class="greyPercent">50%</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When element blueContainer has a height of 2%, I want the text in both paragraphs to be 2%. I want the paragraph text to always show the height in percentage of blueContainer. Height values are applied through an external CSS file,  I am not very well versed in the language of Javascript, and I've tried some ways but I cannot figure out how I should do this.

EDIT: Some of the things I've tried (and probably miserably failed at):

```
function percentages(){
     document.getElementByClassName("greyPercent, bluePercent"){
         if (document.getElementByClassName("greyContainer, blueContainer"){
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I'm stuck at too, because I have no idea how I could tell the javascript to run the function when the element has a certain height.

EDIT: Here is a jsfiddle to illustrate what I'm doing. I gave the containers a background colour because of a lack of images.

https://jsfiddle.net/1s5tw6es/

Comment: we would like to know what are those things you have tried! :)

Comment: Is a height of div varies after page shown, or defined in CSS?

Comment: the height of the div is defined in the CSS right now. This is so that the one who I'm making it for can easily implement it on his website.

Comment: are you expecting like this? (not to handle window resize etc.) `update css -> reload page -> (update text automatically)`

Comment: basically, I need some javascript to show the height of the blueContainer in the paragraph in percentages whenever the height has been changed. Changes can occur because a different javascript has been set up to change the height of the element or by directly editing the css itself. The whole thing is going to be a preloader for a webpage. The blue part will "fill" the grey area, and at the same time the paragraphs show the progress in percentage.

Comment: I've added the images to the fiddle to better illustrate what's happening

Comment: In your situation, I think that creating function which change both the height and the paragraph is easy way.

Comment: Well, sure, if you truly think that's best. Should I ask a new question for that?

Comment: `resize` event used in Dhruv's code is not good for this case because it fired when the browser window's size is changed. I found related question http://stackoverflow.com/q/9628450/2818869.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9628472/2818869.

> First, There is no such css-changes event out of the box, but you can 
>   create one by your own, as `onchange` is for `:input` elements only.
>   not for css changes.
>
> There are two ways to track css changes.
>
> 1. Examine the DOM element for css changes every x time(500 milliseconds in the example).
> 2. Trigger an event when **you** change the element css.
> 3. Use the `DOMAttrModified` mutation event. But it's deprecated, so I'll skip on it.

Nowadays, there are more solutions.

- [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) (If you can drop old IEs)
- [CSS Element Queries](http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/)

---

But in this case, I would create function like `setProgress` which change both the element height and the paragraph.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/e59u3p4j/1/

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. Had to do only a small bit of tinkering, but it's working like a charm now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$("document").ready(function(){  //In case you didn't use this

    $(window).resize(function(){
            $('#bluePercent').html($('.blueContainer').css('height')/16.0*100); //Converting height into percentage and adding it to the p tag
        });
});
```

Comment: I pasted the javascript into my js file but when I changed the height of blueContainer,  the paragraph did not change.

Comment: `(` is missing before `'.blueContainer'`.

Comment: @TobyvanKempen also you must add script tag which loads jQuery if not yet.

Comment: @unarist Yeah, like so, right?

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Also, making it `(''+$('.blueContainer')` did not work.

Comment: Are you getting an error message?If so please paste it over here.

Comment: I forgot that `css('height')` doesn't reflect real size of box because it gets just css value.

Comment: @unarist what do you mean?

Comment: @DhruvRamani oh, it was my misunderstanding like "css('height') reflects only style attr or css file". sorry.

Comment: I tried your new code but it still doesn't work. There are no error messages. I'm sorry if I come off as quick or rude.

Comment: @DhruvRamani FYI: I replace `$('.blueContainer').resize` with `$(window).resize`, it worked.

Comment: Thanks @unarist! I edited it now @Toby. Should work now. Please upvote :)

Comment: @dhruv I'm really sorry to say this, but I added it and altered the height of the element in chrome but it still didn't change the content of the paragraph. It did jump the element up when I resized the browser, though.

Comment: Could you perhaps make a fiddle of your project? Maybe I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: @dhruv @toby I'm sorry for not explaining clearly. `resize` event is works with my fix, but `resize` event is not suitable for this problem because it observes only browser resizing. see http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: I am kind of busy currently. I am will surely make a fiddle within an hour