# Addclass when div width is greater than 80%

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to addclass when div width is greater than 80% ? 
This is what I just tried

```
<div class="wrap_bar">
    <div class="bar" style="width:50%;"></div>
</div>
<div class="box"></div>


    <script>
                     var barTotal = $(".bar");
                     var box= $(".box");
                     var width = barTotal.width();
                     if (width > 80%)
                     box.addClass('type2')
    </script>
```

This code is not working well. Please help

Comment: Try getting the width of the div's paren'ts width and comparing it to the div's width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need this dimension detection only one time (when DOM loaded) then you can just following approach.

```
function addWhenResized(element){
    var parentWidth = $(element).parent().width();
    var elementWIdth = $(element).width();
    if( (elementWIdth / parentWidth)*100 > 79){
        $('.box').addClass('type2');
    } 
    else {
        $('.box').removeClass('type2');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    addWhenResized('.bar');
})
```

But main challenge will be there if you want detect the run time dimension change. Then need to take help from here: http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/

After added the plugins from above given link you should follow the following approach:

```
function addWhenResized(element){
    var parentWidth = $(element).parent().width();
    var elementWIdth = $(element).width();
    if( (elementWIdth / parentWidth)*100 > 79){
        $('.box').addClass('type2');
    } 
    else {
        $('.box').removeClass('type2');
    }
}

new ResizeSensor(jQuery('.bar'), function(){ 
    addWhenResized('.bar');
});
```

Comment: // Great. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
     var barTotal = $(".bar");
     var barTotalWidth = barTotal.width();
     var box= $(".box");
     var boxWidth = box.width();
     var widthPercent = boxWidth / barTotalWidth;
     console.log(widthPercent);
     if (widthPercent > 0.8)
     box.addClass('type2');
  });
                     
</script>

<div class="bar" style="width:200px;height:100px;background-color:red"> </div>
<div class="box" style="width:190px;height:80px;background-color:blue"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your codes don't work because you've just called javascript once when the page loaded , you have to wrap it into an event !
Take a look 
[that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492683/how-to-detect-divs-dimension-changed)

or [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628450/jquery-how-to-determine-if-a-div-changes-its-height-or-any-css-attribute)

Comment: Please include the relevant info in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
if ($(this).width() > 768) {
    $('#service-1').addClass('row text-center');
 } else {
    $('#service-1').removeClass('row text-center');
 }
});
```

this will work fantastic when width is less than or more than will add or remove the class