# Is there any way to set a resize function when screen width changes and it triggers a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually i have a hover function which triggers on mouse hover and i want to work this function only on screen size > 768 px as on touch screen there no point to have this function. I have achieved this by adding an if statement in in a javascript function as follow:and placing my jquery inside this function.

function hoverFunction() {
  if ($(window).width() >760 ){

}
}

now this  hoverFunction() is called twice once onchange and one onwindow load. Now lets talk about the problem. When i load the page and using developer tools move from large screen seize to small the hover function doen not disable even below 768 px until i refresh the page or i trigger the onchange function. it happens same when i move from small to large screen size, i have to either refresh the page i use onchange. is there any way to over come this issue.

Comment: thank you all for your valuable input. actually i am new to javascript. i tried to fix it but could not do so. can any one please explain how can i attach this resize with my hover function so that each time when screen size changes it checks the if screen with is > 760 and then triggers hover function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with `window.onresize`, check the example here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event

Answer (score 0):

you need to attach it on [resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) event, it will trigger on every screen size change

Comment: thank you all for your valuable input. actually i am new to javascript. i tried to fix it but could not do so. can any one please explain how can i attach this resize with my hover function so that each time when screen size changes it checks the if screen with is > 760 and then triggers hover function

Answer (score 0):

Please visit below link , this is how you can trigger your custom function using jquery
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/15114048/7300804

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `window.addEventListener('resize', reportWindowSize);` For this event `reportWindowSize` will be triggered lot of times thus you should use debounced[https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf] `reportWindowSize`. for debouncing in javascript you can refer this[https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce]