# Center a flexible div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have this div which holds a form that has validation messages fade in and out changing the width and height of the div. I have some jQuery to center the div but the problem Im having is when the validation messages fade in and resize the div the jQuery doesn't respond.

I need some code to listen to the width & height of the div?

**The code I have currently**

```
resizeElement = '.blurHolder';

var holderHeight = jQuery(resizeElement).outerHeight();
var holderWidth = jQuery(resizeElement).outerWidth();

jQuery(resizeElement).css({
    'margin-top': - holderHeight / 2,
    'margin-left': - holderWidth / 2
});
```

Any Help?

Comment: You may find this useful http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/

Answer (score 0):

change the position code so that it is the `'margin-top' : (holderHeight/2) - (divHeight/2)`

and apply that for the margin left too. Also what is the position set too, absolute or relative

Answer (score 0):

try this:

html

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="blurHolder"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container{
    background: orange;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}

.container .blurHolder{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #333;
}
```

js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var containerHeight = $('.container').height();
    var containerWidth = $('.container').width();
    var offsetTop = (containerHeight - $('.container').find('.blurHolder').height())/2;
    var offsetLeft = (containerWidth - $('.container').find('.blurHolder').width())/2;

    $('.container').css({'padding-top': offsetTop, 'padding-left': offsetLeft, 'height': containerHeight - offsetTop, 'width': containerWidth - offsetLeft});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just googled a [library](http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/).

It looks like you can detect `onresize` event for the `div` as easy as writing:

```
new ResizeSensor($('#someDiv'), yourCallbackFunction);
```

By the way. There is a native `onresize` event, but it is only supported by IE, as you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19417592/2600208)