# AngularDart Element onResize event not linked to window

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm working on a responsive, full-width layout and I need to do some element processing when the size changes. This has to not be linked to the window, as the size can change without the window size being modified e.g. changing number of columns.

I'm working with AngularDart directives and components and it would be nice to have a directive say, "resizable" which implements such an event for the element.

I've come across the attributeChanged() method in the Dart Element class but don't really know how to tap into that without creating custom elements.

Comment: I tried to implement this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329530 in Dart but I didn't succeed because I encountered this bug: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18062 - please star.

Comment: Is there an example of "resizable" being implemented outside of Angular-land or Dart-land?  Or is this question more of a feature request?

Comment: I got it working. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406549