# Bootstrap 4 resize text into a div responsive

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to resize a text that is inside a div, like this
[example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_resize).

When i resize the div, also the font-size must be resized.

I try to set the text element with pure css with all the relative length units, but doesn't work. The font-size must be depends only by div size (so vw is not appropriate). The only alternative that I think is set font-size by javascript.

```html
<style> 
div {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 300px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
</style>

<div>
  <p style="font-size: 2rem">Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Which is the best way, preferably in bootstrap 4 or pure css ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show what you tried. This is not a request site. Consider reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: show your css and html

Comment: don't think you can do that w/B4 or pure CSS. Think you have to use JS

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Question.
[Onresize for div elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329530/onresize-for-div-elements/19417592)

You can change this:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('my_element'),
    myResizeFn = function(){
        /* do something on resize */
    };
addResizeListener(myElement, myResizeFn);
removeResizeListener(myElement, myResizeFn);
```

Into

```
 var myElement = document.getElementById('my_element'),
    myResizeFn = function(){
        document.getElementById(*ID OF OBJECT*).style.fontSize = "20%"; //use % or vh/vw f.e.

    };
addResizeListener(myElement, myResizeFn);
removeResizeListener(myElement, myResizeFn);
```