# How can I detect when a certain DIV has changed size without polling? I.e., I want a resize event listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am running ads on a website that I have and one of the ads periodically changes the dimensions of the DIV that it is in -- it grows and shrinks and shows bouncing things and flashing lights and sparkles, etc.  This is fantastic and I love it.

One problem, however, is that the layout of other elements on my page is screwed up when this happens.

This is no big deal though -- all I have to do is add an event listener to the DIV element in question and listen for resizing events.  When they occur, I will run a callback function that will adjust the layout of the other elements of my site.

My problem is that the `resize` event listener is only available for the window object itself, not for other elements in the DOM. How can I listen for resizing events on a particular DIV without polling?

I would like to do something like:

```
$('my-div-id').on('resize', function() {
    do_things();
    adjust_layout();
    etc();
});
```

Comment: _...shows bouncing things and flashing lights and sparkles, etc. This is fantastic and I love it._  This is a joke, right?

Comment: @PaulAbbott not a joke -- I am just embracing digital advertising whole-heartedly.

Comment: How about comparing, say, the height of the div to the 'standard' height, and if it's different, do something?

Comment: Could you just record width/height of div, and periodically check again to see if it is different and then do xyz?

Comment: All the responses that involve periodic checking violate my stated objective of not using polling.

Comment: is this what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect DIV's dimension changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492683/how-to-detect-divs-dimension-changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a window.setInterval, that checks every x ms if the element in question has changed size:

```
var ElementSize = $("#element").width();
window.setInterval(function(){
    if( $("#element").width() != ElementSize )
    {
        ElementSize = $("#element").width();
        redolayout();
    }
}, 50);

function redolayout()
{
   // Add code here to resize other elements according to the change.
}
```

Another option: https://github.com/sdecima/javascript-detect-element-resize

Comment: I would like to avoid polling, as my question states.

Comment: The option from sdecima looks like it is exactly what I want.  Thanks.