# DIV onresize event

Tags: javascript, html

div doesn't have onresize. Is there a simply way to call myFunction when div will resized?
p.s. I' m changing div's size via another function not on browser resizing

```
<div onresize="myFunction()" id =5 style="width:50px; background-color:red">
text
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492683/how-to-detect-divs-dimension-changed

Comment: How is the div going to be resized?

Comment: I' m changing div size via another function not on browser resizing

Comment: So than when you change the size, you should trigger an event on that element.

Comment: In that case, why not just call through to your div's resize handler from the calling function?

Comment: [MDN: Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Comment: Because I'm using some ready js which is so complicated that I don't want to understand :)

Comment: Or just simply check the div height/width, and if changed, fire your script.

Comment: @user3123521: What is the function that is resizing the div? You can override it? function blah(){}; var temp = blah; function blah(){ temp(); do what I want after the DIV is resized }