# How to perform change detection on div resizing

Tags: resize, angular, angular2-changedetection

I use Bootstrap for my layout and I need to check if the automatic calculated size of my `div` with bootstrap for example width = 25% is changed.

How to perform change detection on a attribute which I don't set in my template, but is set by Bootstrap?

`(window:resize)` is not enough.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can add a directive to the `div` and implement lifecycle hook `ngDoCheck()` to perform your own change detection logic.  You'll need to inject `ElementRef`:

```
constructor(private _elRef:ElementRef) {}
ngDoCheck() {
   // use ElementRef to examine the div property of interest
```

If the `div` is inside a component template, add a local template variable

```
<div #myDiv ...>
```

Then use `@ViewChild()` to get a reference to the `div` and implement lifecycle hook `ngDoCheck()` or `ngAfterViewChecked()` to perform your own change detection logic.

```
@ViewChild('myDiv') theDiv:ElementRef;
ngAfterViewChecked() {
   // use this.theDiv to examine the div property of interest
```

Note that ngDoCheck() and ngAfterViewChecked() will be called every time change detection runs.  See also the dev guide [Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html).

Comment: The solution in this problem does not work for me because I need to know the real SIZE (w x h) of the div. My div has a relative width 33,33% and this does not change. But the effective size of the DIV changed on do some things in my APP.

the problem is if I do in ngDoCheck something like that
new Ruler(DOM).measure(this.elementRef).then((rect: Rectangle) => { console.log(rect.width); }); }
to check the real width I get a loop, I don't know why but calling masure whil do a change on dom and so there is a infite loop on componente. Some ideas?

But I can use this solution for other problems =)

Comment: `measure()` (or the promise it returns) is likely monkey-patched by Zone.js, so when the asynchronous event fires (and after the event handler runs), Angular's hook runs change detection again.  You can solve this problem by running your code outside of the Angular zone.  Inject [NgZone](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/NgZone-class.html), then check your div size outside the zone:  `this._ngZone.runOutsideAngular(_ => {  // ... check div size here });`.

Comment: I implement your solution, doing a relative complicate logic to check if I had to reset the height, because DoCheck is called also on much other events, for example on hovering the div but there is no need to reset the height.
DoCheck is not called on resize window, so I also added (window:resize) to component which calls the same logic to set and calc new height if needed.

Comment: Avoid using doCheck as much as you can; if not configured correctly, could cause huge performance issues.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem so I used the lightweight library called Angular-Resize-Event

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-resize-event

```
<div (resized)="onResized($event)"></div>
```

After installing it just add this output event to any div which you want to check for size changes.

Comment: a warm reminder, child component might need to call changeDetectionReference if there is a change in its values to notify parent and avoid expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked, e.g. this.cdr.detectChanges();

Answer (score -1):

I have tried the correct answer but the refresh rate wasn't very accurate, So I looked for another solution.

Here it is

```
// Directive
@Directive({
  selector: '[resize-detector]',
})

public constructor(public element: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {}

public ngOnInit(): void {
// Call detectResize as whe the element inits the windows resize event most likely won't trigger
  this.detectResize();
}

// if you need the windowDimensions add ", [$event]" to @HostListener and pass event to detectResize(event)
@HostListener('window:resize') 
public detectResize(): void {
  console.log(element.nativeElement.offsetWidth);
  console.log(element.nativeElement.offsetHeight);
  // Do you magic here ...
}
```

Then you can use it in any element like:

```
<app-component resize-detector></app-component>
```

Comment: It works only when resizing the window, but if there is some interactive element changing our target's size, it won't be recorded.

Answer (score -3):

There are few methods to track DOM attribute changes:

- polling i.e. `setInterval`
- DOM mutation [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events): `DOMAttrModified` + `propertychange` for IE
- implementing [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: MutuationObserver works good, but I noticed I need a little bit more than an observer for attribute, because my DIV WIDTH is always 33,33% I need to know when the real calculated SIZE of my DIC container changed. Some idea?

Comment: you need something like `window.getComputedStyle(element)`

Comment: yea, but when should I call this? I can't call it on MutationObserver because the attribute is not  changed it is still 33,33%

Comment: ok, there is another [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32746473/can-i-use-a-mutationobserver-to-listen-for-changes-on-computed-styles)

Comment: ok, but there are still several problems
1) I'm not able to attach an listener for 'ontransitionend' it seems there is no event for this in angular2
2) as you can see on this plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/UJ9gOpBJti30oTx5lhLL?p=preview there are a containerDIV and a myDIV, on click button for resize containerDIV the transition does not work for myDIV, it works only if I set the width of myDIV ... but my problem is the wrapped component using bootstrap and width 33,33% is autside my component, my component self has 100% width so, the div is resized becouse it is 100% but there is no transition

Comment: the only solution that came to mind is using css media queries. check this [library](http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/)

Comment: that could be also a good solution, for now I resolved my problem yesterday  with the first answer by  @Mark Rajcok, I implement a DoCheck livecycle and do there a relative complicate logic to check if I realy will calculate my size new getting the width value by getComputedStyle, because DoCheck is called to much often also on hover the div, and there I want to recalc the height of the div. I have also set a (window:resize) to component because DoCheck is not called on window resize, I don't know why

Comment: @MichaelBurger, Angular doesn't monkey-patch the window resize event, hence the reason ngDoCheck() is not called when you resize a window.