# Catch event "on document resize" by content-height change

Tags: jquery, events, resize

$(window).resize() is not working if the document-height is changing by a tab-element for example.

How can I catch a document resize event, if the content is changing the document size on the fly?

Comment: Have a look at this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492683/how-to-detect-divs-dimension-changed

Comment: actually i need something like $(document).resize instead of $(window).resize

I was trying to use .bind to catch if the div has changed in size,
but i wasn't able to do so.