# Add/remove class to video element

Tags: javascript, css, video

I'm working on a kiosk-style web page to display a menu of options. Clicking on a title opens a fullscreen video which then closes back to the menu when the video ends.

To keep the page clean, I'd like to hide the `video` element until the video is actually called by a click. I did this with a CSS class. The video opens fullscreen and when finished, closes and adds the `hide` class again.

**Working script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cell').on('click', function() {
    var element = this.getElementsByTagName('video');
    var m = element[0].getAttribute('id');

    console.log(m);
    var v = document.getElementById(m);
    if (v.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      v.className = "";
      v.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }
    v.play();

    $("#" + m).on("ended", function() {
      this.webkitExitFullscreen();
      this.className = "hide";
    });
  })
})
```

I'm running into a problem of the video not hiding if the user exits full screen video on their own. I tried using `$("#" + m).on("ended" || "resize", function()...` based on the HTML5 video API, but that didn't work. I'd also considered disabling clicks or overlaying a full-screen `div` to grab any clicks and force the video to play all the way through, but that seems shady to me. Any ideas on how to approach this?

**[Here's a CodePen demo of the content and script](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/Bjqeob/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Space separated list:

```
$("#" + m).on("ended resize"
```

To make it work you might need this trick: [How to detect DIV's dimension changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492683/how-to-detect-divs-dimension-changed)

Update: I was able to catch the fullscreen event:

```
$(document).on('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange', function(e){
    console.log("fullscreen change");
});
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't do it. I'm wondering if going in/out of fullscreen doesn't count as a resize...?

Comment: maybe if you set up a snippet or jsfiddle, you'll see it for yourself, or at least we can easier help

Comment: Just added to the question.

Comment: Using a space separated list with `ended` and `fullscreenchange` in the same function still didn't work for me, but I can run two different jQuery selectors. Thanks for the help.