# jQuery moving elements on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, appendto

I'm struggling to uncover what the problem is with this jQuery code. I'm trying to move a couple of elements from one div into another. Depending on the width of the screen. The code works on page load, but not when I resize.

```
var domWidth = $(window).width();

//Move around page elements
function moveElements() {
    var pageTitle = $('.page-title'),
        actionAlert = $('.action-alert'),
        banner = $("#banner>.container"),
        header = $("header>.container"),
        mainContent = $(".main-content");

    if (domWidth < 1024) {
        pageTitle.prependTo(mainContent);
        actionAlert.appendTo(header);
    } else {
        pageTitle.appendTo(banner);
        actionAlert.prependTo(banner);
    } 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    moveElements();   
    $(window).resize(function() {
        moveElements();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //Move around page elements
function moveElements() {
  var domWidth = $(window).width();
  var pageTitle = $('.page-title'),
    actionAlert = $('.action-alert'),
    banner = $("#banner >.container"),
    header = $("#header >.container"),
    mainContent = $(".main-content");
  if (domWidth < 1024) {
    pageTitle.prependTo(mainContent);
    actionAlert.appendTo(header);
  } else {
    pageTitle.appendTo(banner);
    actionAlert.prependTo(banner);
  } 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
moveElements();   
$(window).resize(function() {
    moveElements();
});

});
```

> Some Serious edits are made to your code .
>   
>  **the errors in your code are**

1. Main one is you put `var domWidth =$(window).width();`  Outside the function.
   //it should be within the function because you need to find the width each time the function works.
2. You missed to put a # in `header = $("header>.container")`

> For the sake of checking I made a working demo in 
>   https://jsfiddle.net/8m0d1462/
>   (reduced the width to 400 for the sake of checking)

Comment: Thanks for the help. It was because "domWidth" was outside of the function. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the event from the div change listener.

```
$(window).trigger('resize')
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492683/how-to-detect-divs-dimension-changed) to get more idea