# Trigger 'resize' event on component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing a component decorator that is able to detect when a DOM element's size is altered (by css, javascript, window resize etc).

It already works perfectly, I'm now trying to make its API easy to use, so, what's easier than this?

```
class Foobar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div onResize={() => console.log('resized!')}>Foobar</div>;
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(resizeAware(Foobar), app);
```

The problem I'm facing, is that the `onResize` event is not being triggered when I trigger it...

These are two attempts to trigger the event:

```
// method 1
onResize() {
  const resizeEvent = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
  resizeEvent.initEvent('resize', true, true);
  console.log('triggering resize...');
  findDOMNode(this.componentNode).dispatchEvent(resizeEvent);
}

// method 2
onResize() {
    console.log('triggering resize...');
    findDOMNode(this.componentNode).dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
}
```

If I listen for the event with:

```
findDOMNode(this).addEventListener('resize', () => console.log('resized'));
```

Everything works. So it seems like the event I'm dispatching is received by the real DOM element and not by the virtual DOM.

The question now is, why the `onResize` callback is not called?
If there's not a solution, how would you make my decorator API available?

NB: I don't want a way to detect the resize of the component, I just need to dispatch an event to React and make it accessible with `onResize`

Comment: Check out [`react-sizeme`](https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-sizeme). Disclaimer: I am the author. :-)

Comment: I've already a resize event working (it doesn't use any timer internally) https://github.com/FezVrasta/react-resize-aware I just want to improve its API

Answer (score 8):

[Another NPM lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-resize-detector) to listen to resize event of a div. Check the [demo](http://maslianok.github.io/react-resize-detector/)

Comment: This package really helped me

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helped me find the best package for me : [React Resize Observer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-resize-observer), lighter and same approach. Only, when using multiple instances, React Resize Detector keep rendering indefinitely the last Component that wrapped ChartJS graph. React Resize Observer handle this perfectly for me.

Answer (score 4):

I used this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492683/how-to-detect-divs-dimension-changed/46555778#46555778) and simply convert that to a React component. All you need to do is to define a MutationObserver in componentDidMount so it can watch for resize

```js
class ResizableDiv extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.ref = React.createRef();
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        const element = this.ref.current;
        element.addEventListener('resize', (event) => console.log(event.detail));
        function checkResize(mutations) {
            const el = mutations[0].target;
            const w = el.clientWidth;
            const h = el.clientHeight;

            const isChange = mutations
                .map((m) => `${m.oldValue}`)
                .some((prev) => prev.indexOf(`width: ${w}px`) === -1 || prev.indexOf(`height: ${h}px`) === -1);

            if (!isChange) { return; }
            const event = new CustomEvent('resize', { detail: { width: w, height: h } });
            el.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
        const observer = new MutationObserver(checkResize);
        observer.observe(element, { attributes: true, attributeOldValue: true, attributeFilter: ['style'] });
    }
    
    
    render() {
      return ( <div ref={this.ref} className='drag'> Resize me! < /div>);
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render( < ResizableDiv / > ,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

```css
.drag {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="root" />
```