# What's the elegant way to know when child component dimension has changed in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, resize, dimensions

I have been working with React.js for quite a while and have this issue that keeps bothering me.

I'm wondering whether there's a better way to know when child's dimensions have changed instead of just adding an event listener to the DOM itself.

An unknown event, unknown technique??

Comment: One would assume you would hook up [this library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492683/how-to-detect-divs-dimension-changed) and then hook it up to a react callback function