# 'ResizeObserver' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting the error: `'ResizeObserver' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here` when attempting to use ResizeObserver in React with TypeScript.

I have the following interface defined as TypeScript does not include definitions:

```
interface ResizeObserver {
    observe(target: Element): void;
    unobserve(target: Element): void;
    disconnect(): void;
}
```

And I am using it in the following component:

```
const useWidth = () => {

    const ref = useRef<HTMLObjectElement>(null);

    const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);

    useLayoutEffect(() => {

        var resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => console.log("blah blah blah"))
        resizeObserver.observe(ref.current)

        return () => resizeObserver.disconnect()

    }, [ref.current])

    return [ref, width];
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should install the [`@types/resize-observer-browser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/resize-observer-browser) npm package, [to get the type declarations](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/resize-observer-browser/index.d.ts). If you really want to roll your own, you can define a newable interface via a `declare var` in a `*.d.ts` file.

```
declare interface ResizeObserver {
  observe(target: Element): void;
  unobserve(target: Element): void;
  disconnect(): void;
}

declare var ResizeObserver: {
  prototype: ResizeObserver;
  new(callback: ResizeObserverCallback): ResizeObserver;
};

interface ResizeObserverSize {
    inlineSize: number;
    blockSize: number;
}

type ResizeObserverCallback = (entries: ReadonlyArray<ResizeObserverEntry>, observer: ResizeObserver) => void;

interface ResizeObserverEntry {
    readonly target: Element;
    readonly contentRect: DOMRectReadOnly;
    readonly borderBoxSize: ResizeObserverSize;
    readonly contentBoxSize: ResizeObserverSize;
}
```

It'll be available globally then (as I believe it is in the browser) and you can new it up:

[image]

Comment: Do I need to import the @types/resize-observer-browser package in anyway after doing `npm install`? The types don't seem to be being picked up. Thanks

Comment: in your tsconfig, if you have a "types" entry then typescript will only use those - you need to add `resize-observer-browser` to that list.

Comment: I had `node_modules/@types` in my `typeRoots`, thought that was enough. Adding `resize-observer-browser` explicitly to `types` as well fixed the issue. Thank you!