# Calling a function in javascript when the height of a div reaches certain pixel

Tags: javascript

I would like to run a function that would run when the box width reaches certain pixel, lets say 80px. lets say I want to alert "hello" and console.log "hey".
How would i be able to accomplish this? And I can't use jQuery, so just vanilla Javascript please.

Edit: I wonder if I could insert something like a function that runs the alert or console log when `redbox.style.width == "80px"`?

```js
const redbox = document.querySelector("#redbox");
const coolbutton = document.querySelector("#coolbutton");

coolbutton.addEventListener("click", animator);
function animator() {
  if (redbox.style.width == "50px") {
   redbox.style.width = "100px";
   redbox.style.transition = "2s";
  } 
  else {
   redbox.style.width = "50px";
   redbox.style.transition = "2s";
  }
}
```

```css
#redbox {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="redbox"></div>
<button id="coolbutton">click</button>
```

Comment: *80% of what*? Do you wish to show down or change animation for last 20%?

Comment: This might help [detect resize of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492683/how-to-detect-divs-dimension-changed)

Comment: You can use `.resize()` of jQuery. https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: I meant to say 80px sorry. And I cant use jQuery so it hast to be plain javascript.

Comment: mutation observer? or polling...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up, there is no event handler (natively) for during an animation transition.  There is however [one for transition end](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) that would work natively with your code, but since you want to grab its width during the middle, without jquery, that complicates things.

I have little experience with [request animation frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) but for now, after tinkering a bit with your code, here is a structure using a good old fashioned setinterval timer that should get you started with what you want to do.

```
const redbox = document.querySelector("#redbox");
redbox.style.width = `50px`;
const coolbutton = document.querySelector("#coolbutton");
coolbutton.addEventListener("click", animator);
let toggle = true;
function animator() {
  let poller = setInterval(function(){
    let w = parseInt(redbox.style.width, 10);
    toggle ? w++ : w--;
    redbox.style.width = w + 'px';
    if (w == 100 || w == 50){          
      toggle = !toggle;
      clearInterval(poller);
    }
    if (w == 80)
      log(redbox.style.width);
  }, 20);
} 

function log(args){
  console.log(args);
}
```

fiddlers: https://jsfiddle.net/2mkxx6f0/4/

Answer (score -1):

please check the code it is not for 80% it is for `>80px`

```js
var redbox = document.querySelector("#redbox");
var coolbutton = document.querySelector("#coolbutton");
coolbutton.addEventListener("click", animator);
function animator() {
var a= Number("50");// increasing by 50 px
var b=Number(redbox.style.width.slice(0, -2));

  if (b <= 80) {
  var c=b+a+"px";
  
   redbox.style.width =c; 
   redbox.style.transition = "2s";
  } 
  else {
   alert("hii")
  }
}
```

```css
#redbox {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="redbox"></div>
<button id="coolbutton">click</button>
</body>
```

Comment: From where did `1000px` came?

Comment: you can considor it as 80px , `when the box width reaches certain pixel, lets say 80px. lets say I want to alert "hello" and console.log "hey".`

Comment: why downvote ,just check @craftdeer and let him decide is it correct or not?