# Hide div when iframe gets to certain height automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

My users book an appointment on our website which changes the height of an iframe when the iframe has changed height I want to hide the  above the iframe automatically. This is what I have so far the limitation is it only works on the following events but I want it to hide the  dynamically rather than on page re-size or scroll as these events dont take place

```
$(window).on('load resize scroll', function() {
  if ($(".remove-text").height() >= 582) {
    $("#execphp-30, #execphp-47, #execphp-48").hide();
  } else {
    $("#execphp-30, #execphp-47, #execphp-48").show();
  };
});
```

I use the iframeresizer js plugin to detect dynamically update the height of the iframe

Comment: any help with this?

Comment: This part is confusing... "I want to hide the above the iframe automatically". Nevermind. I see in the title 'Hide div'.

Comment: Check this out... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492683/how-to-detect-divs-dimension-changed

Comment: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer#resizedcallback

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {

$(window).on('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
  if ($(".remove-text").height() >= 582) {
    $("#execphp-30, #execphp-47, #execphp-48").hide();
  } else {
    $("#execphp-30, #execphp-47, #execphp-48").show();
  };
});

});
</script>
```