# resize event not triggered on div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Take a look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/vxun2Lgg/2/

I've attached a `resize` event listener on `container` div. After opening up dev tools, and modifying the width of `container`, `resize` callback does not get called. What am I missing?

PS:
I am not interested in window resize event, only in `container` div.

```js
var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
container.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  console.log("resizing")
});
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`resize` is only valid for the `window`. [If supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=resizeobserver) you can use [`ResizeObserver`](https://wicg.github.io/ResizeObserver/).

```
new ResizeObserver(() => console.log("resizing")).observe(container);
```

Otherwise, you will probably have to poll using `setInterval` and check the size.

Comment: Is there something similar for divs?

Comment: Added more detail.

Comment: polling? That's a very bad advice. If your div size changed, it's because of an external event. Handle this external event(s).

Comment: @Kaiido: It is very hard to catch every possible source of a resize, especially for responsive layouts. Polling is a bad idea, but it's still the most reliable method, sadly.

Comment: If you ever need to catch every possible sources it's because of a flow in your design. So fix it but don't ever poll.

Comment: @Kaiido: That is... an opinion one can have, i guess.

Answer (score 15):

This answer extends the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49475832/2457251) by providing a **runnable code** in pure JavaScript that you can try on the snippet runner (button at the bottom). I kept the explanations directly on the code.

Believe or not, you only need a 3-line function (the `onresize` function) to simulate the resize event.

Enjoy it!

```js
// This function works like an Event Listener for
// resizing a dom element.
//
// The ResizeObserver calls the callback function
//   whenever the size of the dom_element changes
//   (because it's "observing" the dom_elem)
//
// Do this:
//
//    understand_it_first
//       .then(copy_it)
//       .then(use_it);
//
// THIS IS THE 3-LINE FUNCION YOU WANT TO USE :)
//
const onresize = (dom_elem, callback) => {
  const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => callback() );
  resizeObserver.observe(dom_elem);
};

// USING IT
//

// Using constants to make it easier to read the code
//
const bb = document.getElementById('bad_boss');
const be = document.getElementById('bad_employee');

// Finally, register the observer for the dom_elem
//
onresize(bb, function () {
  be.style.width  = bb.offsetWidth + 'px';
  be.style.height = bb.offsetHeight + 'px';
});
```

```css
#bad_boss, #bad_employee{
  font-size        : 32px;
  height           : 200px;
  width            : 200px;
}
  
/* Colors that Talk*/

#bad_boss {
  background-color : #0badb055;
}
#bad_employee {
  background-color : #0b00c0de;
  color            : #0badc0de;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>ResizeObserver - onresize Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Experiment to resize this <textarea> -->
        <textarea id="bad_boss">Always do whatever I say!</textarea>
        <div id="bad_employee">Always, Boss!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize

> It is still possible to set onresize attributes or use addEventListener() to set a handler on any element.  However, resize events are only fired on (sent to) the window object (document.defaultView).  Only handlers registered on the window object will receive events.

What's the end goal? There is probably an alternative.

Comment: Thanks. yeah there is. It's just that using resize event was simpler :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getBoundingClientRect()` on an element. I have included a code sample that uses polling to get the width of a `div` element and output the result.

```js
let demo = document.getElementById('demo');
let demoInfo = document.getElementById('demo-info');

setInterval(() => {
  let demoSize = demo.getBoundingClientRect();
  demoInfo.innerHTML = demoSize.width;
}, 500);
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#demo{
  display: flex;
  width:50%;
  
  background-color: red;
  
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">Demo Div Element</div>
<p id="demo-info"></p>
```