# How to detect HTMLElement resize when width is set by percentage

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

I'm developing an Angular Component and i use this css code.

```
:host {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The ideia is to make the component as responsive as possible.

My problem is that i need to do some logic whenever my component width changes. The prefered way (MutationObserver) does not working with component width set by percentage because if the with changes it will be always 100% so the callback of the mutation observer doesnt get fired.

I read somewhere about putting the logic in the DoCheck licycle hook, can some one tell me if there are any other good way to do what i nedd?

Comment: Why you don't use the @media query ? If you write some stylesheet you can adapt the component for all screen size.

Comment: I need to write some typescript logic, not css

Comment: What exactly needs to change, what needs to be responsive?

Comment: i need to draw some svg lines and circles

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two options:

1. use the `window.addEventListener('resize', reportWindowSize);` At the first loading you have to save the original dimension of the div and when the window is resized, you check the original vs current dimension of the div and if it is changed do your custom logic.
2. Follow this [CSS Element Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492683/how-to-detect-divs-dimension-changed) library described into that topic.

Comment: Your first sugestion i have already try it and it work as long as the resize comes from the window, but i have a side bar which can grow and shrink changing the component width without triggering the window resize event...

Comment: I think the resize event is only triggered when the size of the window is changed. So I advice you to follow the second options.