# How to stop click count when a div is resizing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a function to check how many times click action is done on a div.
This div has resized functionality. So when I try to resize it, that resize action got to count as clicked on that div. How I can avoid this resize click count.

```js
let i = 0;
$(".resize").click(function(){
  console.log(i++);
});
```

```css
.resize {
  color: rgb(0, 255, 255);
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* Stack snippet specific CSS */
.as-console-wrapper {
  position: initial !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="resize"></div>
```

I want not to increment the value of `i` if div is resized. Only should increment the value of `i` when clicked inside the border of the div.

Comment: Have you tried working with `onresize`. Refer this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize). Cheers

Comment: Can you please post your resize functionality div `code` here as well ?

Comment: This might actually be something browsers want to fix. There is no standard way to distinguish a click inside the little triangle from a click outside it.

Comment: @ElysianStorm as far I know from documentation onresize function is for window resize. But for my case I am resizing the div. :(

Comment: @AlwaysHelping there is no other functionality for resize. I am resizing the div using CSS property.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492683/how-to-detect-divs-dimension-changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492683/how-to-detect-divs-dimension-changed) is really helpful for the provided question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect DIV's dimension changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492683/how-to-detect-divs-dimension-changed)

Comment: @Fokrule does my solution work for you?  [Link to solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62621914/how-to-stop-click-count-when-a-div-is-resizing/62623121#62623121)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const ObserveResize = (function() {
  let store = [];

  function getDimension(el) {
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

    return {
      w: rect.width,
      h: rect.height
    };
  }

  function isResized({
    el,
    d
  }, d2) {
    return Object.keys(d).some(key => d[key] !== d2[key]);
  }

  function isSubscribed(el) {
    return !!store.filter(record => record.el === el).length;
  }

  function unsubscribe(el) {
    store = store.filter(h => h.el !== el);
  }

  function subscribe(el) {
    const unsubscriber = () => unsubscribe(el);

    if (isSubscribed(el)) return unsubscriber;

    const d = getDimension(el);

    store.push({
      el,
      d
    });

    return unsubscriber;
  }

  function run() {
    store.forEach(record => {
      const d2 = getDimension(el);

      if (isResized(record, d2)) {
        record.d = d2;
        el.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"));
      }
    });

    requestAnimationFrame(run);
  }

  run();

  return subscribe;
})();

const el = document.querySelector(".resize");
let clickCount = 0;
let resizing = false;

el.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (resizing) return;

  ++clickCount;

  console.log(`clickCount: ${clickCount}`);
});

function onMouseUp() {
  console.log("After Resize Mouse Up");
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    resizing = false;
  });

  el.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
}

el.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  resizing = true;

  el.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
  el.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
});

const unsubscribe = ObserveResize(el);
```

```css
.resize {
  color: rgb(0, 255, 255);
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}


/* Stack snippet specific CSS */

.as-console-wrapper {
  position: initial !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="resize"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Workable Solution here:

```js
let i = 0;

$('.resize').click(function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).is('.ui-resizable-handle'))
     console.log(i++);
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
}).resizable();
```

```css
.resize.selected { border: 2px solid black;}

.resize {
  color: rgb(0, 255, 255);

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;

  overflow: auto;
}

/* Stack snippet specific CSS */
.as-console-wrapper {
  position: initial !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="resize"></div>
```

Comment: Resize is not working. It is showing `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).click(...).resizable is not a function`. Even in your given answer it is showing this error .

Comment: @Fokrule code is in jquery and the code snippet I can attach  here is in JS .. that's why! Copy the code and paste in JSFiddle editor

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to count how many times the window has been resized and decrease the i so it shows only the times that has been clicked and not been resized.

```
$(".resize").addEventListener(myFunction);
var x =0;
function myFunction(){
x++; 
//Decrease the i with the times that the window has been 
resized
i-=x
}
```