# UseEffect not triggered by dependencies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Someone can help me? I'd be really thankful :)
The problem here is that when the width and height changes, the UseEffect doesn't run again.
This is a textarea that is being resized...

```
const [elem, setElem] = useState<HTMLElement>(document.createElement('textarea'))
const width = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("width");
const height = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("height");

   useEffect(() => {
      setElem(document.getElementById("email") as HTMLElement) 
      console.log(width, height)
   },[elem, width, height])
```

Comment: You're only getting those values when the component re-renders. Just because the window is resized, doesn't mean a component will re-render. You should add an resizing event listener to the window (or text area element) that stores the new width/height in state. That will trigger a re-render

Answer (score 0):

set the width and height using the `useState`.

```
const [width, setWidth] = useState(undefined);
const [height, setHeight] = useState(undefined);


useEffect(() => {
  const getWidth = () => window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("width");

  const getHeight = () => window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("height");
  const resizeListener = () => {
      setWidth(getWidth())
      setHeight(getHeight())
    };

  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeListener);

  resizeListener();
  // Don't foget cleanup!
  return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeListener);
  // There's a dependency on the element, so if that changes, re-run the effect
}, [elem])
```

Attach the resize event listener and update width and height using setWidth and setHeight.

Answer (score 0):

@William-wang has the right idea. Your code wouldn't retrigger the effect because the values never change except potentially when the code re-renders for other reasons.

While his method using a resize listener on the window will update the width and height, it only happens when the window's size changes.

I've modified the code to use the newer [Resize Observer api](https://drafts.csswg.org/resize-observer-1/). More details in [How to detect DIV's dimension changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39312522/13175138).

This way, it's possible to get accurate and up-to-date size changes. The only issue with this approach is that [older browsers don't support it](https://caniuse.com/resizeobserver%27). Though it does seem to be supported by all modern main browsers at this point.

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useRef } = React;
function Example() {
  const elemRef = useRef(null);
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(undefined);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!elemRef.current) {
      return;
    }
    const resizeListener = () => {
      setWidth(elemRef.current.offsetWidth);
      setHeight(elemRef.current.offsetHeight);
    };
    const observer = new ResizeObserver(resizeListener);
    observer.observe(elemRef.current);
    // Don't foget cleanup!
    return () => observer.disconnect();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      width: {width}
      <br />
      height: {height}
      <br />
      <textarea ref={elemRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```