# How to read width of css element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pure-js

So I want this `VarDisk2` element to disappear after `VarDisk1` width reaches more than 70. How can I do this?

```
 <script>
        var VarDisk1 = document.querySelector("Disk1");
        var VarDisk2 = document.getElementsByClassName("Disk2");
        let width = VarDisk1.offsetWidth;

        if(width > 70)
            VarDisk2.style.display = "none";

    </script>
```

Comment: [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) returns a HTML collection, but you are applying a `style` value as if `VarDisk2` is a single element. It is possible that is the only issue.

Comment: provide the html

Comment: And `querySelector` expects an css selector string, as it stands right now, you are selecting the tag `Disk1` which probably does not exist

Comment: What makes `VarDisk1` element change width? Need more information. 
You can check out [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19418065/3733151). This way you can check width of the element every time it changes

Answer (score 1):

For checking all classes

```
<script>
        ...
        var VarDisk2 = document.getElementsByClassName("Disk2");
        let width = VarDisk1.offsetWidth;

        if(width > 70) {
            VarDisk2.forEach(ele => ele.style.display = "none";)
        }

</script>
```

for first class:

```
<script>
        ...
        var VarDisk2 = document.getElementsByClassName("Disk2")[0];
        ...
</script>
```