# How to detect the if the height has reached 70vh and if so get the width?

Tags: javascript, css, calculation

Say I have a container which height is calculated by it's width. Width changes dynamically base on the viewport width of the screen. I want to detect when the height has reached 70vh or any number and if the limit has reached I want to get it's width. That has to happen dynamically base on the viewport width and height. For instance, I load the page and the height has reached 70vh and when it reached 70vh, it's width is say 1072px. I want to do that dynamically. Does any one know any formula to do that??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492683/how-to-detect-divs-dimension-changed

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your script file it will print your screen dimensions for you

```js
const width  = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || 
document.body.clientWidth;
const height = window.innerHeight|| document.documentElement.clientHeight|| 
document.body.clientHeight;

console.log(width);
console.log(height)
document.write("The Height is &nbsp;" + height + "px &nbsp;")
document.write("The width is &nbsp" + width + "px")
```