# How to set an element’s width change listen to the change of another element’s width?

Tags: html, jquery

This is my code, which is not working.

html:

```
<div class=“footerA”> aaaa </div> <div class=“footerB”></div>
```

Jquery

```
$(‘.footerA’).on(‘resize’,function(){ $(‘.footerB’).css(‘width’, $（‘.footerA’).width()) })
```

I expect footerB’s width changes to when footerA’s width change. The change means when I expand/shrink the browser.

But it doesnt work. Please help.

Comment: `rezise` works only on `window`. use `ResizeObserver`

Comment: With further details - such as the (relevant) [mcve] code of your page- this may be possible with CSS rather than requiring JavaScript, or jQuery.

Comment: Also, be sure never to use curly quotes in your code. E.g. never `“` or `‘`. Instead use `"` or `'`

Answer (score 1):

If you want a JS solution, see here:

You cannot bind "resize" to elements, instead use [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver)

Also note that you should use some inline-type element/styling.
`div` elements are `display: block` by default, hence I've added `display: inline-block;` to show this point.

In the snippet, I made `#footerA` editable (like an input) so that you can change the `div`'s content.

```js
const footerA = document.getElementById("footerA");
const footerB = document.getElementById("footerB");

const resizeObserverCallback = () => {
  footerB.style.width = `${footerA.getBoundingClientRect().width}px`;
}

if (footerA && footerB) {
  new ResizeObserver(resizeObserverCallback).observe(footerA)
}
```

```css
.footer {
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="footerA" class="footer" contenteditable="true">aaaa</div>
<div id="footerB" class="footer">bb</div>
```

This question could be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492683/how-to-detect-divs-dimension-changed)

Comment: The `if (footerA && footerB) {` should be around the `new` constructor, not inside the observer API callback.